# After deletion changing id of textbox inside cell id not working

Tags: javascript, html-table, row, tablecolumn

I have table using Javascript and I am deleting the rows using a delete function

After the deletion I am trying to reindex the table cell ids

```
function updateRowCount(){
         var table = document.getElementById("ordertable");
         var rowcountAfterDelete = document.getElementById("ordertable").rows.length;  
         for(var i=1;i<rowcountAfterDelete;i++){ 
              table.rows[i].id="row_"+i;
              table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML=i+"<input type='checkbox' id='chk_" + i + "'>";
              table.rows[i].cells[1].id="notes_"+i;
                table.rows[i].cells[2].id="amount"+i;
          }
}
```

But the following lines not working:

```
table.rows[i].cells[1].id="notes_"+i;
table.rows[i].cells[2].id="amount"+i;
```

`<td>`'s contains input boxes, it will be like this

```
<td><input type="text" title="notes"></td>
<td><input type="text" title="amount"></td>
```

How can I change the id of text box inside `<td>` or cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/an87ka5p/

I updated this to answer the question in the comments

```
function test() {
    var table = document.getElementById("ordertable");
    var rowcountAfterDelete = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowcountAfterDelete; i++) {
        table.rows[i].id = "row_" + i;
        table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i + "<input type='checkbox' id='chk_" + i + "'>";
        table.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id = "notes_" + i;
        table.rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id = "amount_" + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: `table.rows[i].cells[1] `contains a text box. I want to change the id of input box inside that `<td>`. Updated the question please check buddy

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle and my answer, but i'm still not sure that this is what you are asking for

Comment: Thanks buddy this is what I am looking for!!